# Stepwise calculation based on window width in CSS

Tags: css, sass, calc

I need to make a calculation that every 100px of window width + 2% css increased in the left %:

Examples:

- **width > 700px:** `left: 30%`
- **width > 800px:** `left: 32%`

How I can do this?

Comment: use `vw` unit which depend on the screen width

Comment: @TemaniAfif This doesn't seem possible with `vw`. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Sean the question lack some context to know if it's possible or not. I simply gave a hint since `vw` already depend on the screen width

Comment: @TemaniAfif Better to ask for clarification than send someone down a wrong path

Comment: @Sean you concluded it's a *wrong path*. I didn't give any path. I gave a CSS information that he may not know. There is nothing *wrong* in doing this.

Comment: @TemaniAfif What they're asking for isn't possible with `vw`. You told them explicitly to use `vw` in this case; you didn't just make them aware that it exists—that would have been fine.

Comment: @Sean as far as I know, I am free to say what I want ;) and I didn't *answer* this question (otherwise you can downvote it because you think it's *wrong*). I never say it's possible or not possible, that's only *your* conclusion. The answer box is below, you can elaborate an answer and give the correct method.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Just trying to offer constructive feedback that will benefit other users. You're of course free to do as you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not currently possible to write a single CSS ruleset that increments a property *stepwise* every 100 pixels of window width in all major browsers. You'll need to write a separate media query for each interval.

In SCSS, you can do this with a loop. This will create a media query for `$number-of-intervals` number of steps starting at `$base-width` width and `$base-percentage` percentage:

```
$base-width: 600px;
$base-percentage: 30%;
$number-of-intervals: 6;
@for $i from 1 through $number-of-intervals {
  @media screen and (min-width: #{$base-width + (($i - 1) * 100)}) {
    .my-class {
      left: #{$base-percentage + (($i - 1) * 2)};
    }
  }
}
```